# Decode unicode in json

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have code.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import re, json
from pprint import pprint

jsonStr = '{"type":"\u041f\u0435\u043d\u0438","values":{"v1":"222"}}'
data = json.loads(jsonStr)
pprint(data)
```

output

```
{u'type': u'\u041f\u0435\u043d\u0438', u'values': {u'v1': u'222'}}
```

how to get the normal data in 'type'?

thanks to all,
**beautiful output in the console**

```
jsonStr = '{"type":"\u041f\u0435\u043d\u0438","values":{"v1":"222"}}'
data = json.loads(jsonStr.decode("utf-8"))
print json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2).decode("unicode_escape")
```

output

```
{
"type": "Пени", 
"values": {
    "v1": "222"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* normal data:

```
>>> import json
>>> jsonStr = '{"type":"\u041f\u0435\u043d\u0438","values":{"v1":"222"}}'
>>> data = json.loads(jsonStr)
>>> print data['type']
Пени
```

Python containers such as dictionaries and lists show their contents using the `repr()` function; you are looking at *debugger friendly output*, which is ASCII safe. To make it ASCII safe any non-ASCII and non-printable codepoints are shown as escape sequences, so you can copy that output to a Python interpreter and re-create the value safely without having to worry about codecs.

Just use the data as you normally would. I printed the string, so that Python could encode it to my terminal codec and my terminal decoded it and showed the Russian text (cyrillic characters).